# How can I have cleaner code and do less copying/pasting of code (VBA. Python)

Tags: python, vba, copy-paste

I find myself constantly copying code from previous sections of my project into other sections in VBA.

My entire code seems unnecessarily long because this.

Over half my code is copied from one section and pasted in other sections. This is an issue when I realize there's a small error, causing me to go back to correct it in every instance I copied and pasted.

**Is there any way to make my code shorter and to reference copied code only once in VBA, and also python?**

Comment: You probably want to define a function with the shared code and call it once. It might also be possible to structure you code in a loop to much the same effect. I would start maybe with looking at functions.

Comment: Thanks. I use loops a lot. In most scenarios that are looped, I tend to repaste code from other sections.

Comment: This is probably way too general to get a good answer here, but you need to get comfortable with identifying the repeated portions of your code and factoring them out into their own methods (Sub/Function).  If code is *almost* identical with some small variations then the variable parts should be parameters in your factored-out methods.  If you need concrete suggestions then including some example code would be useful.

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/refactoring

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in a general sense; we need to know what code you actually have in order to know whether it can be refactored. That aside, code review questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, unless you are asking for a specific, objective criterion to be met (e.g. "how can I write this code to be `n` LoC or less?" or "how can I achieve this functionality without using a foreach loop?").

Answer (score 0):

I uaually have a module for my functions. they work like a tool box for me. i need to call them always in other subs.they save my time and make my codes more readable. Also debugging is much easier. I recommend the same to you.